# Popup Error while trying to see the values of a specific column in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

This popup keeps showing up while trying to type the name of certain columns into the RStudio Console. I'm wondering if there is a workaround for this.

```
> Error Message: Error in if(nchar(current)>nchars) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

[image]

R Version: 4.3.0

When something like this is typed into the console `object$column_name` it triggers the popup and after I press OK I can continue running the code.

Comment: Seems like something to file an issue https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: Do you have a .Rprofile file somewhere containing some code that could be causing this?